# Getting those errors on my wordpress site (rankmath 404 Monitor)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a new `WordPress` that has only a few posts. I'm using `rankmath` plugins and on 404 monitor of rankmath I'm getting those errors. Point is that I didn't use any kind of file manager plugins. even on I didn't find any plugins files like those on my `Cpanel`. so my question is that why I'm getting those errors and is `wp-file-manager` a default plugin of `WordPress`?

```
wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/files/thumbs.php
wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/files/upload.php
wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/files/accesson.php
wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/files/n.php
wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/js/elFinder.js
```

Comment: WP File Manager is _not_ a default plugin of WordPress, however it _might_ be a default plugin of your host. (Personally, if it is, you might want a different host.) That said, you might just be getting a bunch of false positives. Do those files exist on your disk? Also related, that plugin specifically had a [major issue](https://www.zdnet.com/article/wordpress-file-manager-bug-causing-full-website-takeover-exploited-in-the-wild/) recently, so I wouldn't be surprised if people are just probing your site.

Comment: What are "those errors"?